# Spring Batch JPA Bulk Insert eats performance when using GenerationType.IDENTITY

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-batch

I am using `Spring Boot and Spring Batch and JPA` to load data from One database into another. In a single batch Job I've created `10 steps` to run steps in sequence and each step reads almost `1 millions` records (I can't run in parallel, because data that I've doesn't load in parallel).

I've used `GenerationType.IDENTITY` and look like because of this batch job taking hell lot of time. If I say to load `100 records` it takes `2 min`. The target `Postgres database` has `sequences` implemented by DBA and we must need to follow those, but its eating up all the performance.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "EMP_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
private Long id;
```

How can I improve the performance of this batch job ?

I kept `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=1000` and `chunkSize=1000` as well.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - Hey Thanks. I've replied there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hibernate cannot batch insert entities if the entity is using `IDENTITY` to generate its ID (Also mentioned in the docs at [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-identity)).

So you have to change to use `SEQUENCE` to generate the ID. And according to [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-hidden-gem-the-pooled-lo-optimizer/) , choose to use "pooled" or "pooled-lo" algorithm to get the new ID from the  sequence in order to further improve the performance by reducing the round trips to get the ID.

So the ID mapping looks like :

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="emp_sequence")
@SequenceGenerator(name="emp_sequence", sequenceName = "emp_id_seq", allocationSize = 100)
private Long id;
```

And the hibernate settings :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 1000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data = true


# For using "pool-lo" optimiser for generating ID when using JPA @SequenceGenerator
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.optimizer.pooled.preferred = pooled-lo
```

Also , you have to make sure the corresponding ID sequence in PostreSQL is aligned with the configuration in `@SequenceGenerator` :

```sql
alter sequence emp_id_seq increment by 100;
```

Another tip is to add `reWriteBatchedInserts=true` in the JDBC connection string  which will provides 2-3x performance improvement as said from the [docs](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters).

Comment: Why there is a gap between batch_size = 1000 and allocationSize = 100? Should we keep this same ?

Comment: no need , they can be different values. allocationSize control how many IDs will be `reversed` per each ID generation request. batch_size controls how many records will be batched into one single inserted SQL.

Comment: For anyone wondering why property in settings didn't work, it had a typo

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hibernate.id.optimizer.pooled.preferred = pooled-lo` to `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.optimizer.pooled.preferred = pooled-lo`

Comment: Thanks @JacekLipiec. Good catch. I just updated my answer

Comment: My entity uses UUID.

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
@Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
private UUID UUID;


Is it still eligible for batch processing?

Answer (score 1):

I Jeff

Las year my team and I came across a situation where a job was taking like forever to perform DB write operations.

What we did to improove performance was:

- Use repositories and managed entities just for DB read operations, but never alter those entities, to avoid spring jpa to write the changes in database.
- Create a store procedure for the insert/update operation.
- Call the SP with JDBCBatchItemWriter using index parameters
- Set the parameters with ItemPreparedStatementSetter

That way we coulm improove performance reducing DB calls!

Hope it helps